# node js build script for hosting in aws working in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, build

```json
// package.json:
{
  // ...
  "clean": "rm -rf www/ || true",
  "build": "npm run clean && tsc && copy -rf src/config www/config && cp .npmrc www/.npmrc && cp package.json www/package.json && cd www && zip -r Archive.zip . && cd .."
  // ...
}
```

The `build` script is made for linux. How can it be changed to run on a Windows machine?

Comment: And your problem is?! What have you tried so far?  Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also take a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You say you want it to work on a Windows machine. Do you mean you want something that works on _both Linux and Windows_? Or do you only want/need the answer to work for Windows?